# Gulp - watch strange behaviour

Tags: gulp, watch

I have the following configuration:

```
// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('_01_src/js/**/*.js', ['babel']);
    gulp.watch('_01_src/scss/**/*.scss', ['scss']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['scss', 'babel', 'watch']);
```

If I execute watch alone: "gulp watch" is working with no issue. If I execute "gulp", watch is started but is not working and I don't understand why (I tried changing the position in array but no luck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, it runs `scss`, `babel` and `watch` asynchronously, that could cause problems. Maybe just set `scss` and `babel` to run before `watch` is started at all?

```
// Watch
gulp.task('watch', ['scss', 'babel'], function () {
    gulp.watch('_01_src/js/**/*.js', ['babel']);
    gulp.watch('_01_src/scss/**/*.scss', ['scss']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of list parameters try using `gulp.series()` and `gulp.parallel()`.
So your example would look like:

```js
// Watch
gulp.task('watch', function (done) {
    gulp.watch('_01_src/js/**/*.js', function(){
        gulp.series('babel')();
    });
    gulp.watch('_01_src/scss/**/*.scss', function(){
        gulp.series('scss')();
    });
    done();
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.series(gulp.parallel('scss', 'babel'), 'watch'));
```

This way `scss` and `babel` will run in parallel, and `watch` will run after that.